# Python script causing python.exe crash and wrapped C/C++ object failure

Tags: pyqgis, merge, qgis-processing, pyqt

I am working on automating some of the normal processes that I want to do and I have run into some problems I have not found solutions for after a couple days of searching.

I am relatively new to python / QGIS.

QGIS version 2.16.3 (still occurs in 2.18.0 and 2.18.1)

The issue is that when I run this script (I have pared it down to the essentials for this case that still causes error)  I often (but not every time!! ) get the error:

> python.exe has stopped working

Note that the script still operates as intended!!!  The script works!! but this error causes the script to pause in the middle requiring a click of the OK button.

Also, at the end of the script I get an error:

> wrapped C/C++ object of type QProgressBar has been deleted See log for
>   more details

Log message:

> 2016-10-01T12:42:36   2   Uncaught error while executing algorithm
>               Traceback (most recent call last):
>                 File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.16/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\GeoAlgorithm.py", line 204, in execute
>                   progress.setPercentage(100)
>                 File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.16/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\gui\MessageBarProgress.py", line 55, in setPercentage
>                   self.progress.setValue(i)
>               RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QProgressBar has been deleted

This error happens every time.

I think that this is happening more when the rasters I am operating on are large
(I am merging 4x 40 Mb rasters in this case)

Here is the excerpt of my script pared down to show the actual activities that still cause consistent failures.

I am not sure if this is a problem with my code or something else!

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import *
from qgis.gui import *
import processing
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import time

proj = QgsProject.instance()
proj.clear()

workdir = "C:/QGISwork/ving_script/"
vindef = "FR_83510_00001"
date = "20160830"

proj = QgsProject.instance()
proj.clear()

curfield =1

GRN_raster = workdir + vindef + "_"+ str(curfield).zfill(2) +"_" +date +"_"+ "GRN" + ".tif"
RED_raster = workdir + vindef + "_"+ str(curfield).zfill(2) +"_" +date +"_"+ "RED" + ".tif"
RDE_raster = workdir + vindef + "_"+ str(curfield).zfill(2) +"_" +date +"_"+ "RDE" + ".tif"
NIR_raster = workdir + vindef + "_"+ str(curfield).zfill(2) +"_" +date +"_"+ "NIR" + ".tif"

merge_rast = "C:/QGISwork/ving_script/merge_int_"+str(curfield).zfill(2)+".tif"
print "Field number: " + str(curfield).zfill(2)
print "trying merge"
processing.runalg('gdalogr:merge', GRN_raster + ";" + RED_raster + ";" + RDE_raster + ";" + NIR_raster, True, True, 5, merge_rast)

print "Merge complete"
```